# Flashplayer 10.1, set enhanced seeking to false, without FMS

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, seek

So I run into this issue that Enhanced Seeking is enabled by default. And I would really like to disable it (long story here). But it seems you can only disable it on the FMS, by adding this setting to the application.xml. But the thing is we are not sure if we will end up using an FMS or not. So, can I disable Enhanced Seeking without using FMS?

[seek() reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#seek%28%29)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should just find the closest fileposition to the target time (inside the metadata.keyframes if target time is not loaded yet) and request video from pre-generated keyframe never causing the server to generate one